# Codeigniter Getting error on both array notation and object notation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for my project and couldn't find what's wrong with my code. This is my controller code

```
$products = $this->products_model->getProductsQuantity($id);
$q = $warehouse_product->quantity;
```

**object notation** is working but getting error: **Trying to get property of non-object**

```
$q = $warehouse_product['quantity'];
```

**array notation** not working and getting php error: **Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in products\controllers\products.php on line xx**

Here is my model function

```
public function getProductsQuantity($product_id) 
    {
        $q = $this->db->get_where('products', array('product_id' => $product_id), 1); 
          if( $q->num_rows() > 0 )
          {
            return $q->row();
          } 

          return FALSE;

}
```

Please help me to fins where is the problem in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at this

if you are limiting your results to 1 as in your get_where instruction then return

```
$q->row_array() // for array
```

And

```
$q->result_array() // for object
```

And in Controller do this

```
$products = $this->products_model->getProductsQuantity($id);
$quantity = $products->quantity; // Object notation
```

And

```
$quantity = $products['quantity']; // Array notation
```

Comment: Thank you Raheel, row_array() worked with array notation but $q->result_array() for object notation didn't.

Comment: for object notation it is row() sorry for that take a look at this http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html